# FIWARE Wirecloud: Error using X-FI-WARE-OAuth-Token request header

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

We are part of the FINISH accelerator and are deploying Wirecloud and KeyRock on our own servers using the docker containers provided by fiware.

We have KeyRock-IdM set up and linked to Wirecloud. We are trying to pass the logged-in users token to an API which returns data to a widget.

We found documentation about the "X-FI-WARE..." headers in the github code and wrote a test widget (main.js shown below). When deployed on the fiware labs instance, it works out of the box. When deployed on our local installation with a docker container it gives the following error: "Current user has not an active FIWARE profile". I scoured the settings.py file but have no idea where this error is coming from. I have DEBUG=True but nothing show up in the log. The user running the widget was logged in through the KeyRock IdM.

```
/*jshint globalstrict:true */
/*global MashupPlatform, ObjectStorageAPI, StyledElements*/

(function () { 

"use strict";


var token_available = MashupPlatform.context.get('fiware_token_available');
var username = MashupPlatform.context.get('username');
alert(username + " has token?: " + token_available);

var url = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('keyRock_url');

var request = MashupPlatform.http.makeRequest(url, {
    requestHeaders: {
        "X-FI-WARE-OAuth-Token": "true",
        "X-FI-WARE-OAuth-GET-Parameter": "access_token"
    },
    method: "GET",
    onSuccess: function (response) {
        alert("Success:" + JSON.stringify(response.responseText));
        document.getElementById('response').textContent = response.responseText;
    },
    onFailure: function (response) {
        alert("Failed:" + JSON.stringify(response.responseText));
    },
    onComplete: function () {
    }
}
);


})();
```

How can i find out what is going wrong?

From the comment below, changed a python script:
edited the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/fiware/proxy.py file in the docker container and replaced line 37 from raise ValidationError(error_msg) to a simple raise.

the log from /var/log/apache2/error.log is below

`[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745550 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936] Internal Server Error: /cdp/https/account.lab.fiware.org/user
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745580 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745584 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/proxy/views.py", line 234, in proxy_request
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745587 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]     response = WIRECLOUD_PROXY.do_request(request, url, request_method, workspace)
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745589 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/proxy/views.py", line 144, in do_request
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745592 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]     processor.process_request(request_data)
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745594 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/fiware/proxy.py", line 59, in process_request
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745597 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]     token = get_access_token(request['user'], _('Current user has not an active FIWARE profile'))
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745599 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/fiware/proxy.py", line 33, in get_access_token
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]     if oauth_info.access_token is None:
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745604 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/storage/base.py", line 41, in access_token
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745615 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936]     return self.extra_data.get('access_token')
[Fri May 06 07:12:33.745618 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13:tid 139955375367936] AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Seems a bug, but I want to investigate a bit more before giving you an answer. Can you update the question providing the version of WireCloud and the result of executing `MashupPlatform.context.get('fiware_token_available');` from the widget in your instance.

Comment: Another thing you can tests, while I'm investigating and preparing you some steps for debugging, is to configure your WireCloud instance to use the Account portal from FIWARE Lab instead of using your custom KeyRock instance.

Comment: MashupPlatform.context.get('fiware_token_available')  returns true in my widget.  # wirecloud-admin --version gives version 0.8.4. I am using the latest docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/wirecloud. I will test using the FIWARE Lab portal later today.

Comment: Currently, the latests docker image of WireCloud is on version 0.9.0 ;-), and we are going to update it today or tomorrow to version 0.9.1 :). Anyway, version 0.8.4 of WireCloud should work ;-). One more question, are you using the same domain for the KeyRock and the WireCloud services?

Comment: yes the domain is the same. However i added the following to settings.py to stop Wirecloud complaining: SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'wcsessionid'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'wccsrftoken'

Comment: I tried directing Wirecloud to the FIWARE labs IdM instance. Same result: I can log in fine and MashupPlatform.context.get('fiware_token_available') returns true, but passing the X-FI-WARE-OAuth-Token and associated headers still gives the response: "Current user has not an active FIWARE profile".

Comment: ok, so we have to debug... Please, edit the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wirecloud/fiware/proxy.py` file in your docker container and replace line 37 from `raise ValidationError(error_msg)` to a simple `raise`. This should make WireCloud to provide a more specific error response (instead of just returning the "Current user has not an active FIWARE profile" error message). Update the question with the new messages.

Comment: Yesterday was a public holiday in Holland, so i did not see your comment. I have added the stack trace that appears in /var/log/apache2/error.log in the main question, as it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Docker Hub contains bogus 'Official' images

After trying Alonzo's suggestion and the log not yielding an obvious solution, i decided to double check that the docker image i was using was trustworthy.

It turns out the docker image i was using (wirecloud/fiware-wirecloud) which states to be the official reference implementation is in fact an old version (0.8) owned by someone called 'Wirecloud'. If you search Wirecloud on docker hub or in Kitematic it is the first entry to show up.

I upgraded to the docker image fiware/wirecloud which is version 0.9, and now it works. I can see the access token passed to my back-end services.

Curiously, my test widget which i had modelled on the objectstorage.wgt example on https://wirecloud.conwet.etsiinf.upm.es/slides/attachments/objectstorage.wgt required updating to the new config.xml format before i could test.

I suggest:

- a link to the correct wirecloud image on docker hub in the documentation.
- contacting the 'Wirecloud' user and asking them to change the description of their image, or adding a comment with information about the official docker image.

Comment: We are going to update the object storage widget. Thanks for reporting the problem. Also seems that the wirecloud/fiware-wirecloud image get outdated, although it is an automatic build repository and points to the same github repo as the fiware/wirecloud image. Now it should be updated

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem is related to the use of `python-social-auth` v0.2.18. Please update to v0.2.19. See this [ticket](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/898) in github for more info about this problem.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, in the meanwhile i discovered the docker hub image i was using was not the official version, see my answer.

Comment: fiware/wirecloud points to the same repository as wirecloud/fiware-wirecloud. See the "Source Repository" link in the docker hub  ;-).

Comment: And as of 13 minutes ago it now has latest version = 0.9. An hour ago it was only up to version 0.8. Are you updating it as we speak?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are adding an extra "-". Try "X-fiware-..."

Comment: Tried 
        "X-FIWARE-OAuth-Token" and  "X-FIWARE-OAuth-GET-Parameter". The request is passed to KeyRock all right, but without an access token, which causes KeyRock to return an error "Access Token None not found". The header names were copied verbatim from here: https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/blob/0.9.x-develop/docs/slides/3.1.8_Accessing_third-party_servicies_using_IdM_tokens.md so it seems unlikely i made a mistake in the names.

Comment: Header names were created long time ago... But it's true, we should avoid using the `x-` prefix and the dash in FIWARE. I'm working on it :). See this [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/177) for more info.